# Problem with margin?

Tags: formatting

I have a problem that  the margin on the right and on the left are not equal, and this ""page by page"" for example:

page 5: the margin on the right greater than on the left \ page 6: the margin on the left greater than on the right and vice versa

Iwant that  the pages stay  as well in the middle and this for all pages !! I want that they stay aligned

I am using a \documentclass{these}, it is defined in a (.cls)-file that my advisor sent to me, this (.cls)-file is given as follows:

```
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    
    \ProvidesClass{these}[2007/07/16 classe pour mise en forme de These]
    \LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
    
    \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \RequirePackage{tabularx}
    \RequirePackage{ifthen}
    \RequirePackage[includefoot,nomarginpar,twoside,
        top=27mm,bottom=27mm,
        head=5mm,headsep=7mm,
        footskip=7mm,
        hmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
    
    \newif\if@blankemptypage
    \DeclareOption{noblankemptypage}{\@blankemptypagefalse}
    \DeclareOption{blankemptypage}{\@blankemptypagetrue}
    
    \@blankemptypagefalse
    %\ExecuteOptions{}
    \ProcessOptions
    
    % names
    \newcommand{\@titleapp}{Titre}
    \newcommand{\@engtitleapp}{Title}
    \newcommand{\@resumeapp}{R\'esum\'e}
    \newcommand{\@abstractapp}{Abstract}
    \newcommand{\@keywordsapp}{Mot-clefs}
    \newcommand{\@engkeywordsapp}{Keywords}
    \newcommand{\@juryapp}{Jury}
    \newcommand{\@advisorapp}{Directeur de th\`ese }
    \newcommand{\@coadvisorapp}{Co-directeur de th\`ese}
    \newcommand{\@labapp}{Laboratoire}
    
    % Sets the name of the laboratory
    \newcommand{\@labo}{\textbf{!\texttt{labo} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\labo}[1]{\renewcommand{\@labo}{#1}}
    
    % Sets the name of the school
    \newcommand{\@school}{\textbf{!\texttt{school} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\school}[1]{\renewcommand{\@school}{#1}}
    
    % Sets the name of the phd speciality
    \newcommand{\@speciality}{\textbf{!\texttt{speciality} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\speciality}[1]{\renewcommand{\@speciality}{#1}}
    
    % Sets the name of the university
    \newcommand{\@universityabbrv}{\textbf{!\texttt{universit\'e} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\@university}{\textbf{!\texttt{universit'e} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\university}[2]{
        \renewcommand{\@universityabbrv}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@university}{#2}
    }
    
    % Sets the ISBN number (if not set, prints lines for space to the 10 digits to
    % be written
    \newlength{\@ISBNcolwidth}
    \setlength{\@ISBNcolwidth}{.25em}
    \newcommand{\@ISBN}{
        \begin{tabular}{*{13}{|p{\@ISBNcolwidth}}|}
            &&&&&&&&&\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\renewcommand{\@ISBN}{\texttt{#1}}}
    
    % Sets the advisor name (and title, optional, defaults to M)
    \newcommand{\@advisor}{\textbf{!\texttt{advisor} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\@advisortitle}{M}
    \newcommand{\advisor}[2][M]{
        \renewcommand{\@advisortitle}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@advisor}{#2}
    }
        
    % Sets the coadvisor name (and title, optional, defaults to M)
    \newcommand{\@coadvisor}{\textbf{!\texttt{coadvisor} \`a d\'efinir!}}
    \newcommand{\@coadvisortitle}{M}
    \newcommand{\coadvisor}[2][M]{
        \renewcommand{\@coadvisortitle}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@coadvisor}{#2}
    }
    
    % Defines a member of the jury
    \newcommand{\@jury}{}
    \newcommand{\jury}[1]{\renewcommand{\@jury}{
    \begin{tabular}{r@{ }ll}
    #1
    \end{tabular}
    }}
    \newcommand{\jurymember}[3][M]{#1. &#2, &#3}
    \newcommand{\juryadvisor}[1][Directeur de th\`ese]{
        \jurymember[\@advisortitle]{\@advisor}{#1}
    }
    \newcommand{\jurycoadvisor}[1][Co-directeur de th\`ese]{
        \jurymember[\@coadvisortitle]{\@coadvisor}{#1}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\@labaddr}{}
    \newcommand{\labaddr}[1]{
        \renewcommand{\@labaddr}{#1}
    }
    \newcommand{\@engtitle}{}
    \newcommand{\engtitle}[1]{
        \renewcommand{\@engtitle}{#1}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\@resume}{}
    \newcommand{\@abstract}{}
    \newcommand{\resume}[2]{
        \renewcommand{\@resume}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@abstract}{#2}
        \chapter{\@resumeapp}
        \@resume
    
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@abstract}{}}{}{
            \@openrightfalse
            \chapter{\@abstractapp}
            \@openrighttrue
            \@abstract
        }
    }
    
    \newcommand{\@keywords}{}
    \newcommand{\@engkeywords}{}
    \newcommand{\keywords}[2]{
        \renewcommand{\@keywords}{#1}
        \renewcommand{\@engkeywords}{#2}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\@resumesize}{\small}
    \newcommand{\resumesize}[1]{\renewcommand{\@resumesize}{#1}}
        
    % redefine the \maketitle command
    \renewcommand{\maketitle}{
        \begin{titlepage}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
    %\geometry{nomarginpar,noheadfoot,twoside,showframe,
    %    top=15mm,bottom=20mm,
    %    hmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm}
    %        \vsize = 277mm
    %        \voffset = -15mm
    %        \topmargin = 0mm
    %        \headheight = 0mm
    %        \headsep = 0mm
    %        \hsize = 160mm
    %        \hoffset = -10mm
    %        \vbox to \vsize {
                \begin{center}
                    \textsc{\@university}
                \end{center}
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                \begin{flushright}
                    \parbox{6cm}{
                       % \begin{center}
                        %    N{$^\circ$} attribu\'e par la biblioth\`eque\\
                         %   \texttt{\@ISBN}
                        %\end{center}
                    }
                \end{flushright}
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                \begin{center}
                    {\Large\textbf{TH\`ESE}}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
                    pour obtenir le grade de\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                    \textbf{\textsc{Docteur} de \@universityabbrv}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                    Sp\'ecialit\'e : \textbf{\@speciality}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                    pr\'epar\'ee au laboratoire \textbf{\@labo}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                    dans le cadre de l'\'Ecole Doctorale \textbf{\@school}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
                    pr\'esent\'ee et soutenue publiquement\\
                    par\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
                    {\Large\textbf{\@author}}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
                    le \@date\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{5}}
                    \@titleapp :\\
                    {\large\textbf{\@title}}\\
                    \vspace*{\stretch{5}}
                    \@advisorapp : \textbf{\@advisor}\\
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@coadvisor}{}}{}{
                        \@coadvisorapp : \textbf{\@coadvisor}\\
                    }
                    \vspace*{\stretch{8}}
                    {\large \@juryapp}\\
                    \@jury
                \end{center}
    %        }
        \end{titlepage}
    }
    
    % Back page
    \newcommand{\@backsection}[5][r]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{%
        }{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\noindent\textbf{\textsc{#2}}%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{\\}{}}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{\indent}{\noindent}{#4{#3}}\\%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{%
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
                \noindent\rule{\hsize}{1pt}%
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
            }{}%
         }%
    }
    \newcommand{\makeback}{
        \begin{titlepage}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \null\clearpage
            \thispagestyle{empty}
    %        \vsize = 277mm
    %        \voffset = -15mm
    %        \topmargin = 0mm
    %        \headheight = 0mm
    %        \headsep = 0mm
    %        \hsize = 160mm
    %        \hoffset = -10mm
    %        \vbox to \vsize {
                \noindent\rule{\hsize}{1pt}
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                \@backsection{\@resumeapp}{\@resume}{\@resumesize}
                \@backsection{\@keywordsapp}{\@keywords}{\@resumesize}
                \@backsection{\@engtitleapp}{\@title}{\bf}
                \@backsection{\@abstractapp}{\@abstract}{\@resumesize}
                \@backsection{\@engkeywordsapp}{\@engkeywords}{\@resumesize}
                \@backsection[]{Adrr : }{\@labaddr}{\@resumesize}%
                \@backsection[]{ISBN : }{\@ISBN}{}
    %            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    %            \noindent\textbf{\textsc{ISBN}} : {\@resumesize{\@ISBN}}
    %            \noindent\textbf{\textsc{ISBN}} : {\@resumesize{\@ISBN}}
        \end{titlepage}
    }
    
    % fancy pagestyle redefinition
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\leftmark}
        \fancyhead[LO,C,RE]{}
        \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small\rightmark}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
    % plain pagestyle redefinition
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \fancyhead[L,C,R]{}
        \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[LO,C,RE]{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    \renewcommand\thepart           {\@Roman\c@part}
    \renewcommand\thechapter        {\@arabic\c@chapter}
    \renewcommand\thesection        {\@arabic\c@section}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection     {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
    \renewcommand\thesubsubsection  {\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
    \renewcommand\theparagraph      {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
    \renewcommand\thesubparagraph   {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
    
    \newcommand{\openany}{\@openrightfalse}
    \newcommand{\openright}{\@openrighttrue}
    
    \newif{\if@frontmatter}
    \renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
        \cleardoublepage
        \@mainmatterfalse
        \@frontmattertrue
        \pagenumbering{roman}}
    \renewcommand{\mainmatter}{
        \cleardoublepage
        \@mainmattertrue
        \@frontmatterfalse
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
    }
    \renewcommand{\backmatter}{
        \if@openright
            \cleardoublepage
        \else
            \clearpage
        \fi
        \@mainmatterfalse
        \@frontmatterfalse
    }
    
    \def\@chapter[#1]#2{
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \if@mainmatter
                \refstepcounter{chapter}
                \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
                {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
            \else
                \if@frontmatter
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
                \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{toto#1}
                \fi
            \fi
        \else
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
        \fi
        \chaptermark{#1}
        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
        \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
        \if@twocolumn
            \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]
        \else
            \@makechapterhead{#2}
            \@afterheading
        \fi
    }
    
    \let\@oldschapter\@schapter
    \def\@schapter#1{%
        \@oldschapter{#1}%
        \if@mainmatter
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{#1}}
        \else
            \if@frontmatter
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
            \else
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
            \fi
        \fi
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    }
    
    \if@blankemptypage
        %Redefine cleardoublepage so that the pages inserted are really empty
        \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
            \clearpage
            \if@twoside
                \ifodd
                    \c@page
                \else
                    \null
                    \thispagestyle{empty} %set style empty
                    \newpage
                    \if@twocolumn\null\newpage\fi
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    \fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `\RequirePackage[...]{geometry}` delete the `bindingoffset=10mm`.

Traditionally in a book type document an outer margin is equal to the sum of the inner margins so that when the book is opened the outer margins and gutter are equal. How will your advisor feel if you change the layout of your document from what was specified in the class file that was sent to you?

I suggest that you don't change the margins unless it is for something other than your thesis, and even then I suggest that you don't change them. --- GOM